# Toggle heatmap in fusion table layers

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, heatmap

Is there any techniques which enables fusion table heatmap option to true in initial loading only. ie, if I have a fusion table map layer with 5k+ markers, then I want to enable heat map only at first loading of the map after that it should set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you create the map and layer:

```
 var ftOpts = {
  query: {
     select: location_column,
     from: table_id
  },
  heatmap: {
    enabled: true           
  } 
};

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(ftOpts);
layer.setMap(map);
```

Then on zoomin:

```
layer.setOptions( {
   heatmap: { enabled: false}
});
```